# Issue in applying str.contains across multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe:

```
col1          col2             col3
132jh.2ad3    34.2             65
298.487       9879.87          1kjh8kjn0
98.47         79.8             90
8763.3        7hkj7kjb.k23l    67
69.3          3765.9           3510
```

Desired output:

```
col1          col2             col3
98.47         79.8             90
69.3          3765.9           3510
```

What I have tried: (this doesn't delete all rows with alpha-numeric vales)

```
df=df[~df['col1'].astype(str).str.contains(r'[A-Ba-b]')] #for col1
df=df[~df['col2'].astype(str).str.contains(r'[A-Ba-b]')] #for col2
df=df[~df['col3'].astype(str).str.contains(r'[A-Ba-b]')] #for col3
```

I want to delete all alphanumeric rows, and have only the rows containing numbers alone. Col1 and Col2 has decimal points, but Col3 has only whole numbers.
I have tried few other similar threads, but it didn't work.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: you should change `'[A-Ba-b]'` to `'[A-Za-z]'`

Comment: So sorry, I just noticed it. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
df[~df.apply(lambda row: row.str.contains(r'[A-Z]', flags=re.I).any(), axis=1)]
```

(*import re* required).

Your regex contained *[A-B]*, but it should match **all** letters
(from *A* to *Z*).

## Edit

If you have also **other** columns, but you want to limit your criterion
to just your 3 **indicated** columns, assuming that they are consecutive columns, run:

```
df[~df.loc[:, 'col1':'col3'].apply(lambda row:
    row.str.contains(r'[A-Z]', flags=re.I).any(), axis=1)]
```

This way you apply the same function as above to just these 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks @Valdi_Bo, when I have more columns like `col4, col5` in my dataframe, this would be applied to all the columns right ? Is there a way to specify `col1, col2, col3` alone using `apply()  and lambda`

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `to_numeric`:

```
df[df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notnull().all(1)]
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2  col3
2  98.47    79.8    90
4   69.3  3765.9  3510
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not require the use `apply` (which can be slow) but rather `stack`

```
# stack and use isnumeric to see if str is a number or float
# then unstack and dropna
df[df.stack().str.replace('.','').str.isnumeric().unstack()].dropna()

    col1    col2  col3
2  98.47    79.8    90
4   69.3  3765.9  3510
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris, is it possible to specify this for few columns alone like df.iloc[:,2:3] ?